# TF broadcaster on robot , where to start?

Tags: ros, python, tf-broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey , i am new to ROS . Currently i am working on this robot(http://)(http://)(http://).

components

1. sabertooth 2x32 motor driver
2. 18aH 12v battery
3. raspberry pi
4. Logitech USB camera
5. Line laser
6. 2X 250watt ebike motors

The current configuration doesn't have a encoders . This is a big issue for determining the odom .

The bot is currently partially ROS enabled (Skid steer ) . I want to configure the bot with TF such that the camera and wheels are in the right perspective .

I am not able to figure out where to start , should i write a URDF/XACRO description of the robot and add the camera to it ?

If anyone knows some simple tutorials please point me towards that .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275539/tf-broadcaster-on-robot-,-where-to-start?/) by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2017-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-10**:
I've given you enough karma to attach images. Please *edit* your question to add the image in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have somewhat of an expression in my lab:

> If you're using ROS, but don't have a urdf, you're doing it wrong

that is of course grossly generalising, but there is some truth there.

Whether or not you have encoders, start creating a urdf modelling the structure of your robot.

Worry about adding other things later (such as "TF broadcasters": you'll know when you need them, right now, you don't yet).

Also note: encoders (ie: wheels) are not the only source of odometry. Visual odometry and IMUs are also good sources.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on 2017-11-10**:
Thanks , you are right . I should leave everything and first focus on creating the URDF model . I am already on it .